# GetSelectedItemIds using pnp.js.core

Tags: pnp-js-core

In JSOM we have a method called `SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems()`

How do I do this using `pnp.js.core`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, pnp.js.core is pure REST/API. Still need to use Jsom.